# Calling a java method in Mysql query-java

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

i have searched on the internet on how i can get values from a method called  in mysql query, whereby it only returns identical values for all rows in a column,what can i do so that i get the respective values in each row when the method is called.I need help please.My method for getting results is as follows:

```
public final void getResults() {
   // from = (String) empol.getSelectedItem();
    resultsTable=new JTable();
    model=new DefaultTableModel();
    int i;
    int count;
    String a[];
    String header[] =  { "Name","Date","Basic","Commision","Allowances","NSSF","Deductions","PAYE","Gross","Net"};   //Table Header Values, change, as your wish
    count = header.length;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        model.addColumn(header[i]);
    }
    resultsTable.setModel(model);                             
    docwin.add(resultsTable.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);

    a = new String[count];
    try {
        dbconn.connect();
        st = dbconn.conn.createStatement();
        SQL = "select money.Name, money.Date, money.earnings,money.commision,(SELECT SUM(Amount) "
                + "  FROM allowances where allowances.Name=money.Name) as Allowance,(select nssf_amount from nhif where "
                +"nhif.Name=money.Name ) as NSSF, (SELECT SUM(Amount) "
                + " FROM deductions where deductions.Name=money.Name ) as deductions,'"+getTax1()+"' as Paye, "
                + " (SELECT (earnings +commision + (SELECT SUM(Amount) "
                + "  FROM allowances where allowances.Name=money.Name))) as GrossPay,"
                + "(SELECT ((SELECT (earnings +commision + (SELECT SUM(Amount) "
                + "  FROM allowances where allowances.Name=money.Name)))) - "
                + "((SELECT SUM(Amount)"
                + " FROM deductions where deductions.Name=money.Name )+(SELECT nhif_amount FROM nhif where nhif.Name=money.Name )+ "
                + "(earnings * 0.16)+(select nssf_amount from nhif where "
                +"nhif.Name=money.Name ) ) ) as NetPay "
                + "from money Group by Name order by money.monid ";
        rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);
         while (rs.next()){
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
                a[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            model.addRow(a);                //Adding the row in table model
            resultsTable.setModel(model);             // set the model in jtable
        }

        pane = new JScrollPane(resultsTable);
        docwin.add(pane);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

the method that is invoked is this:

```
public String getTax1() throws SQLException {

    String result="";
    String s = "select (money.earnings + money.commision+(select sum(Amount) from allowances where allowances.Name=money.Name)) as Total from money ";
    Statement sts;
    ResultSet rst;
    sts = dbconn.conn.createStatement();
    rst = sts.executeQuery(s);
    while (rst.next()) {
        result = rst.getString("Total");
    }
    // return result;
    int gross= Integer.parseInt(result);

    final double ftx1 = 10165;
    final double ftx2 = 9576;
    final double ftx3 = 9576;
    final double ftx4 = 9576;
    final double ftx5 = 0;
    // the percentage of fedral tax
    final double taxper1 = 0.10;
    final double taxper2 = 0.15;
    final double taxper3 = 0.20;
    final double taxper4 = 0.25;
    final double taxper5 = 0.30;
    Double relief=1162.0;
    // double theincome = in.nextDouble();
    //1st cut
    double thing1 = Math.min(ftx1, gross);
    double taxd1 = thing1 * taxper1;
    double thinga = Math.max(gross - ftx1, 0);
    //2nd cut
    double thing2 = Math.min(ftx2, thinga);
    double taxd2 = thing2 * taxper2;
    double thingb = Math.max(thinga - ftx2, 0);
    //3rd cut
    double thing3 = Math.min(ftx3, thingb);
    double taxd3 = thing3 * taxper3;
    double thingc = Math.max(thingb - ftx3, 0);
    //4th cut
    double thing4 = Math.min(ftx4, thingc);
    double taxd4 = thing4 * taxper4;
    double thingd = Math.max(thingc - ftx4, 0);
    //5th cut
    double thing5 = Math.max(ftx5, thingd);
    double taxd5 = thing5 * taxper5;
    //total federal tax-tft
    double tft = taxd1 + taxd2 + taxd3 + taxd4 + taxd5;

    double tax=tft-relief;
    netTax1=Double.toString(tax);

    return netTax1;
}
```

All it does is that it gives one identical PAYE value for all employees,what can i do to make it show respective tax values in the jtable?
kindly help

Comment: So basically you want to display return value of `getTax1` against each employee on the `JTable`? And looking at the method `getTax1` it is going to return same value no matter what employee we are interested in - correct?

Comment: So what is the error your are getting or is it working? is `st.executeQuery` throwing `SQLException`?

Comment: @ring,i am not getting any error,all it does it picks the value for the first employee and puts it in all other employees.i want it get tax and show for each and every employee in each respective row in the PAYE column

Comment: yes i want it to show the return value against each employee @ring

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to have different `getTax1()` value returned per employee. That can not be achieved by adding `getTax1` call to the SQL. What you have essentially done is added a constant value in the `SELECT` clause and by that you ensured for each row the query returns there will always be a constant value added to the field list, which is the return value of `getTax1()` call.

In order to get it working as you wish you need to either:  Add the expression needed to compute `PAYE` per employee (join using some ID that makes sense to your application) **or** do a computation per employee record using following steps.

In `getResults` method :

```
Execute query to fetch all the details except `PAYE` field that you want to compute. 
For each employee in the result    
    Call `getTax1` with employee ID as parameter to get corresponding value
    Add return value to the array that makes the table model. 
Done
```

You need to change `getTax1` logic to accept an Id or other fields that lets you compute require value per employee.

Comment: ,pardon a bit,how can i call getax1 with id,please dont mind...if possible,asample

Comment: @kazisto : Per your comment, the `getTax1` would change per employee. That means the query inside `getTax1` should contain some conditions specific to an employee. Currently the query in `getTax1` is kind of static - it is going to return same value no matter what. So you need to re-design that query. At that point, it will become clear to you what values you need to pass as dynamic values to the query. They should be part of your method signature. HTH

Comment: which condition shall i use sir?I have tried ".....where allowances.Name=money.Name" but it shows the same thing....

Comment: @kazisto :) I can not advise on this because I do not know anything about your data model.

Comment: just stranded in my project...help please